# Using erlang to build a snmp service: how can I get MIB to use its instrumentation functions?

Tags: erlang, snmp

I'm using erlang to build a snmp service.I have defined some MIB files (eg., EX1-MIB.mib), their associated files (eg., EX1-MIB.funcs) and their instrumentation functions (eg., ex1.erl) in the same directory. I started the snmp service and loaded the MIB on both agent and manager, started the instrumentation module, then I used `snmpm:sync_get/3` to get what I need from the agent. This is the part I have problems with:

> snmpm:sync_get("simple_user", "otp agent", [[1,3,6,1,3,7,1,0]]).
>   {ok,{noError,0,
>                [{varbind,[1,3,6,1,3,7,1,0],'OCTET STRING',[],1}]},
>       4971}

`[1,3,6,1,3,7,1]` is the OID of a variable I'm trying to get, but the return is `[]`. I assume it didn't use my instrumentation module and I wonder why.
(I'm sure my instrumentation module works fine and can return a tuple `{value, XXX}`.)

The example I used came from the [Agent Implementation Example documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/snmp/snmp_impl_example_agent.html). You can see the EX1-MIB.mib, EX1-MIB.funcs and ex1.erl files in this link.

Comment: What value did you expect instead, and why?

Answer (score 0):

If you used the linked example without modifications, than after starting the instrumentation with `ex1:start().` the server will respond with the default values: `myName` is an empty string and there are no rows in the `friendsTable`.

The value your manager received (`[]`) is the empty string, the default value for `myName`. So it looks like your instrumentation module could be working just fine.

You can verify that this is indeed the case by e.g.:

- Tracing on the `ex1_server` process while calling `snmpm:sync_get/3` to see that it handles the `get_my_name` message as expected.
- Changing the default value of the name in `ex1.erl`:

```erlang
init() ->
    register(ex1_server, self()),
    loop("newDefault", []).
```

- Sending an snmp set request first to set a non-default value.